# Number of group homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

How many group homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z} $

I know that a generator should be mapped to a generator in a homomorphism. But I am unable to proceed in this problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is enough to figure out what happens to the generators of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$; they must map to elements of order dividing $3$, $4$, and $9$, respectively.

Comment: “generator should be mapped to a generator” is only true if your domain is cyclic and you want the map to be surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any such will be determined by where it sends $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.  And the orders of the images divide $3,4$ and $9$ respectively.  There are $3$ elements of order dividing $3$, $2$ of order dividing $4$, and $9$ of order dividing $9$, by cyclicity.  So,  $3\cdot2\cdot9=54$.